# Joint Hypothesis Testing-Variance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, variance, expected-value, covariance

Got the following question:

[image]

Here is the provided answer:

[image]

I am confused about where the $9$ coefficient is coming from above. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hint: what is the variance formula for a linear combination of random variables? e.g. if you have $Z=aX+bY$, where $X$ and $Y$ are R.V.s and $a$ and $b$ are constants, what's the variance of $Y$?

Answer (score 4):

A more general result is as follows. Let $X, Y$ be random variables, with $E(X) = \mu_1, E(Y) = \mu_2$, $\text{var}(X) = \sigma_1^2$, $\text{var}(Y) = \sigma_2^2$ and $\text{cov}(X,Y) = \sigma_{12}$.

Then, for any reals $n,m$,

$$E(nX + mY) = nE(X)+mE(Y) = n\mu_1+m\mu_2,$$

$$
\text{var}(nX) = n^2\text{var}(X) = n^2 \sigma_1^2,
$$
$$\text{cov}(nX, mY) = n\cdot m\cdot\text{cov}({X,Y}) = nm\sigma_{12},$$

and

\begin{align*}
E[(nX + mY)^2] &= E(n^2 Y^2 + nmXY + m^2Y^2)\\
& = n^2E(Y^2) + nmE(XY) + m^2 E(Y^2)\\
& = n^2(\sigma_1^2+\mu_1^2) + nm(\sigma_{12}+\mu_1\mu_2) + m^2 (\sigma_2^2+\mu_2^2)\\
\end{align*}

thus
\begin{align*}
\text{var}(nX+mY) &= E(nX+mY-E(nX+mY))^2\\
&=E\left\{(nX+mY)^2 - 2(nX+mY)E((nX+mY) + [E(nX+mY)]^2\right\}\\
&= E[(nX + mY)^2] - [E(nX+mY)]^2\\
&= \ldots \text{ (check!) }\\
&= n^2\sigma_1^2 + m^2\sigma_2^2 +2nm\sigma_{12}.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, by the same token, you can show that

$$\text{var}(nX-mY) = n^2\sigma_1^2 + m^2\sigma_{2}^2 - 2nm\sigma_{12}.$$